# How to make animation with constrains in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have programmed a bars graph when each bar is `UIView` with constraints on its height and top constraint to the superview.

Once they values for the heights are inputted, an animation should be performed with 10 seconds duration.

However, the animation does not occur.

I first calculate the new height of the bar:

```swift
let portion = Float(self.currentValue!) / Float(self.maxValue!) // portion of max height of the bar
let newTopConstraint = Float(maxTopConstraint) * portion // the new distance from the top of the superview

var heightDiff = newTopConstraint - Float(self.barTopConstraint.constant)
heightDiff = abs(heightDiff)
```

Now that I got the new height for the bar, I want to animate it to that position:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
    self.barTopConstraint.constant = newTopConstraint
    self.heightCons.constant += heightDiff
    self.barView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Unfortunately, the animation never occurs. What is wrong with my animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Replace your animation code with this:

```swift
barTopConstraint.constant = newTopConstraint
heightCons.constant += heightDiff

UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: view.layoutIfNeeded)
```

When you update constraints, just setting the constant to something else doesn't update the view.

To update the view, call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view you want to update the constraints for.

In this case, I'm calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the main view, so every subview will also be updated.

In the future, if you want to update constraints with no animation then call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` right after setting the constant. When you want an animation, put `layoutIfNeeded` inside of `UIView.animate`.

Comment: When you update constraints, just setting the constant to something else doesn't update the view. To update the view, call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view you want to update the constraints for. In this case, I'm calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the main view, so every subview will also be updated. In the future, if you want to update constraints with no animation then call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` right after setting the constant. When you want an animation, put `layoutIfNeeded` inside of `UIView.animate`.

Comment: Also, the last line is the same as `UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }`, just in a fancier way.